# Json not decoding

Tags: php, json, post, curl

Me encuentro haciendo una petición en curl en cuyo caso funciona de maravilla en postman sin embargo el problema empieza cuando la quiero hacer en php

Resultado en Postman:

```
POST/GET url: http://xxxxxxxxxxxx/post/read.php?acct_num=xxxxxxxxxxx
Current Response is:
{"Numero de Cuenta":"xxxxxxxxx","Casa":"xxxxxxxxxxxxx  ","Apertura":"xxx-xx-xx","Fecha Ult Compra":"xxxx-xx-xx"}
```

pero cuando la hago en curl todo falla
Peticion en curl:

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => $url,
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
  'Accept-Encoding: application/json'
  ),
  //CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true

));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
$fresp = print_r(json_decode($response));
$error = json_last_error();
var_dump($json, $error === JSON_ERROR_UTF8);
fwrite($guardame, $fresp . PHP_EOL);//Mi Metodo un poco tonto de loggear errores
fwrite($guardame, $error . PHP_EOL);
```

Mi archivo de log:

```
http://xxxxxxxxxx/post/read.php?acct_num=xxxxxxxxxxx
1
0
```

Sin embargo si no uso `json_decode` el resultado es igual al de postman

he gastado bastante tiempo buscando pero parece que no lo hago correctamente le importaría a alguien proveer alguna pista?

Comment: Que tienes si haces var_dump($response) cuando lanzas en php, te llega hasta hay la ejecución, igual busca otras opciones para curl

Comment: esa peticion en curl fue generada desde postman, por alguna extraña razon postman gusta mucho de los arrays y el caso de curl no es la excepcion en mi caso en lugar de generar la peticion con php desde postman la genere en modo curl bash posteriormente use [curl-to-php](https://reqbin.com)  para generar el codigo y problema resuelto

Comment: cambiando mi peticion del array provisto antes por este 
```
<?php

$url = "http://xxxxxxxxxx/post/read.php?acct_num=xxxxxxxxxxxx";

$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$headers = array(
   "Content-Length: 0",
);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
//for debug only!
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$resp = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
var_dump($resp);

?>
```